# run haskell ghci without having admin privilege

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm setting up the environment to learn haskell and I'm able to compile programs using `ghc`, however, I can't invoke the `ghci` interpreter.

Below is the error:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.6.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: user specified .o/.so/.DLL could not be loaded (addDLL: pthread or dependencies not loaded. (Win32 error 5))
Whilst trying to load:  (dynamic) pthread
Additional directories searched:   C:/Users/theuser/bin/ghc-9.6.2-x86_64-unknown-mingw32/mingw/lib/clang/14.0.6
   C:/Users/theuser/bin/ghc-9.6.2-x86_64-unknown-mingw32/lib/../mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
   C:/Users/theuser/bin/ghc-9.6.2-x86_64-unknown-mingw32/lib/../mingw/lib
   C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

I know one of the common solutions to this problem is to  [add a permission for "Users" to read & execute pthread.dll](https://faculty-web.msoe.edu/hasker/cs3040/ghc-install.html), however I just can't do this. I'm not allowed to run any command as admin.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637459/ghci-on-windows-10-error-user-specified-o-so-dll-could-not-be-loaded-adddll) doesn't help because all answers involve running `ghci` as admin directly or indirectly by granting access to my User to the `pthread.dll`.

How can I have `ghci` without having admin rights?

I'm on windows 10.

Comment: Eurgh, Windows without admin privilege? Honestly, you'll be best off requesting to install VirtualBox and then run a Linux VM. Or rent a machine in the cloud. I reckon it _is_ also possible with Windows sans admin, but it will be pain upon pain.

Comment: Can you run WSL? You can install Haskell there and the integration with VS code works pretty well.

Comment: Can't you ask permision for that dll?. Or ask an admin to install the tool and change the permisions on the fly, so you don't have to run `ghci` as admin. I mean... that's how permissions work

Comment: Nope, i can't install VirtualBox or WSL. As they all require admin privilege to get installed. Apparently it's almost a "must" to have admin privilege to have access to `ghci`.

Comment: Currently I also have a laptop with Windows and no admin rights. I installed all the Haskell stuff with **ghcup** and everything works fine.